# reactjs material ui Backdrop

Tags: reactjs

I see document [text](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-backdrop/)

there is an example, when you click on the button, Backdrop is shown.
How can we manage the Backdrop state (setOpen(false); / setOpen(true); ) outside function

I don't know how to implement it

How change state backdrop from another reactjs file

Comment: There is a code example right below the button in MUI docs

Answer (score 1):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Backdrop from '@mui/material/Backdrop';
import CircularProgress from '@mui/material/CircularProgress';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';

export default function SimpleBackdrop() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };
  const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={handleOpen}>Show backdrop</Button>
      <Backdrop
        sx={{ color: '#fff', zIndex: (theme) => theme.zIndex.drawer + 1 }}
        open={open}
        onClick={handleClose}
      >
        <CircularProgress color="inherit" />
      </Backdrop>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yes it is this sample and? i need change open state not button click

Comment: Is that new file a child of this component?